# Don't let user leave my app

Tags: android, home-button

I'm developing and app that is going to be installed on a tablet. I'm going to rent this tablet to a person and I don't want this person to leave my application, I mean, I only want that tablet to use my app. I don't want the person to have access to other applications that it's not my app, even if the tablet is turned off, when restarted I would like my app to start first. 
I've tried to change home button and so on, but it's not possible. 
Can anybody give me a hint? I would appreciate any help

Answer (score 0):

> 1. Make your activity full screen.
>
> 2 Use an alarmManager to trigger your activity from a service on a
>   regular interval say 2or3 second (only if your activity is not
>   foreground). For this use a boolean variable and store it using
>   sharedPreference. this value will be true in onReume and false in
>   onPause or in onStop or in onDestroy. And then only start your
>   activity from your service if the boolean variable is false. Now if
>   your user will press the Home button then AlaramManager kick start
>   your activiy again.
>
> 3 Make a special button for finishing your service and activity and
>   for cancel the alarmManager.

I found this answer on this post:

[It is possible to make a HoneyComb activity unclosable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9371614/it-is-possible-to-make-a-honeycomb-activity-unclosable)

Comment: This won't work. User can still exit the app using home and recent apps button. Also, by restarting the tab.